# installing drivers to kubuntu without internet

Tags: drivers, software-installation, kubuntu

How can one install drivers to Kubuntu without any internet access?

Every guide to installing drivers that I've seen online requires an internet connection. But how would one go about finding the drivers online (say, in Windows on a browser), downloading them to a USB drive, and then installing the drivers onto Kubuntu?

In particular, I'm interested in knowing where to find the drivers, and how to install them once I've transferred them over to my Kubuntu file system.

These are the drivers I need:

- NETGEAR A6210 Wifi USB 3.0 Adapter
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Answer (score 1):

You can find the nvidia driver nvidia-common-updates as .deb (debian install package) [HERE](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/misc/nvidia-current-updates), choose 64 or 32 bit, put on a USB double click in KUbuntu to install.

Same for the WIFI driver, from research I believe this to be the one from the repo or "additional drivers" for your USB, go [HERE](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/broadcom-sta), choose your Ubuntu version from the bottom, go down to "Binary packages built by this source" and choose "broadcom-sta-common", you need to get the latest (release) version, download is on the right.